# how retrieve check box data from data base in the front end asp.net c# coding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some value stored in the database from the check box and again when I open the page I need the check box value to be checked as it already has some data.
Can any body help

Comment: which part is giving you trouble? can you show your code?

Comment: i have not done any coding. I need some coding to show the check box checked or unchecked by looking the value from the database..

Answer (score 0):

In the Form Loaded event you should read your checkbox's stored value from the database then assign it to the checkbox's Checked property.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      myCheckBox.Checked = database.isChecked;
    }
```

Then in the checkbox's changed events you can save the state back to the database:

```
private void myCheckBox_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      database.isChecked = myCheckBox.Checked;
}
```

you can read a little more about events from here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/form